# change ContextMenu based on layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to change my `ContextMenu` based on my `layout` - and for that i need to determine
what layout i`m using after the long click was clicked.

- how can i determine my layout name ?
- how can i use 2 different ContextMenu`s in one activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i determine my layout name ?

You must know it when you set it surely?

In your `Activity` set an instance member to the layout...

```
int myLayout = -1;

protected void onCreate(...) {

    if (foo)
        myLayout = R.layout.foo;
    else
        myLayout = R.layout.bar;

        setContentView(myLayout);
}
```

> how can i use 2 different ContextMenu`s in one activity

You can use any number of context menus in one `Activity`. You can have a different context menu for every single UI element in the `Activity` if you really want to. In other words each `EditText` or `ImageView` and so on can have its own. You just have to register them.

See the docs for [onCreateContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu%28android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo%29) for how you create each context menu depending on which view it is.